# Replace function is not working with boundary in python while replacing

Tags: python, regex

i want to replace the word only "order" , not "orders" with "replace"

```
import re
a = """order orders Order"""
x = a.replace(r"order","replace")
print(x)
#replace replaces
```

also when i give boundary, its showing error

```
import re
a = """order orders Order"""
x = a.replace(r'\b'+order+r'\b',"replace")
print(x)
#NameError: name 'order' is not defined
```

i want to replace only order, not orders. Can anyone help me out.

I am expecting output as :
"""replace orders Order"""

Comment: its syntax error, you have not defined `order` or probably you need ``a.replace(r'\border\b',"replace")`` ??

Comment: i just need to replace the word "order" with anything say "replace" keywords. That all. M i doing any mistake ?? please let me knoe @sushanth bhai

Comment: Please provide a sample input(s) and expected output(s) (a few words with order and/or orders and what you expect as a result)

Comment: @JanStránský I am expecting output as :
"""replace orders Order"""

Comment: note that `replace` method doesn't support regex, only fixed strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re.sub` and this regex:

```py
import re
a = """order orders Order"""
x = re.sub(r"order(?=[^s])","replace",a)
print(x)
```

- `[^s]` ... character not being "s"
- `(?=...)` ... lookahead, checks if it is true (no "s" in this case), but does not includes it in the match

EDIT: a better regexp also working if the string ends with `order`:

```py
import re
a = """order orders Order order"""
x = re.sub(r"order(?=$|[^s])","replace",a)
print(x)
```

- `$|[^s]` ... end of string or not "s"

Comment: Thanks Jan. But this [^s] will only for "s". Instead of [^s] i guess this will be more appropriate. x = re.sub(r"order(?=[^a-z])","replace",a) ? Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: This is exactly why I asked you for sample inputs and expected outputs. The OP mentions just "orders" as unwanted..

Answer (score 1):

You should try following solution.

```
import re
a = """order orders Order"""
x = re.sub(r"\border\b", "replace", a)
print(x)
```

Comment: the solution with `\b` is maybe a better solution than the lookahead (depending on specific needs)

Answer (score 0):

As @Jan suggested, I have got the answer.

```
import re
a = """order orders Order"""
x = re.sub(r"order(?=[^a-z])","replace",a)
print(x)
```

#replace orders Order